# My Emerald Arborvitaes are Yellowing on the Inside!

Tags: trees

I live in Utah and the weather is getting a bit colder. About a month ago all my of trees were going very strong, all green throughout, but now they are starting to yellow from the inside out. This makes me so sad. They are getting plenty of water from a drip line I installed this summer. Is there anything I can do for them?

Here's the weather for my zip code:

https://www.google.com/search?q=weather%2084601

And a picture:

[image]

And a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBGoQvLfJSI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: How long have they been planted?

Comment: I planted them all this summer in June

Answer (score 1):

This is undoubtedly an issue with watering - you say you have a dripline installed, but its possible that the rootballs of the plants did not receive sufficient water, even though the soil around them might be damp. If you want to check that's the problem, dig one up and inspect the rootball; it may have put out a few roots further than the rootball, but they're unlikely to be many, particularly if the rootball was dry.

Unfortunately, once a part of these plants has gone brown, it will not regenerate in that area, and will remain brown.